# How to get corpora in Java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, bad-request

I want to get the list of corpora.

`curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx(about 1200 characters IAM token)" "https://https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/zzzzz(customization_id)/corpora"`

result(This curl command succeeds.)

```
{"corpora": [
   {
      "out_of_vocabulary_words": 0,
      "total_words": 10,
      "name": "corpusname",
      "status": "analyzed"
   },
...
```

but...in Java,

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;

try {
    String urlStr ="https://https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/zzzzz(customization_id)/corpora";

    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String token = xxxxxxxx; // about 1200 characters IAM token

    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    urlConn.connect();

    int status = urlConn.getResponseCode();
    String resMessage = urlConn.getResponseMessage();
    System.out.println("## HTTPStatus:" + status + " - " + resMessage);  // "## HTTPStatus:400 - Bad Request"

} catch (xxx) {
    // ...
}
```

result(failure)

```
## HTTPStatus:400 - Bad Request
```

I used same IAM token...
Why this error occurs?

(I'm sorry that I am not good at English.)

=============added 2020/03/03

I used watson SDK(ver.6.9.2). But another error(403) occurs...

```
IamOptions options = new IamOptions.Builder()
                    .accessToken(token)
                    .url(urlStr)  // String urlStr = https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/zzzzz(customization_id)/corpora
                    .build();

SpeechToText speechToText = new SpeechToText(options);
System.out.println();

ListCorporaOptions listCorporaOptions = new ListCorporaOptions.Builder()
                                        .customizationId(customizations_id)  // String curstomization_id = zzzzz
                                        .build();

List<Corpus> corpus = speechToText.listCorpora(listCorporaOptions)
                                  .execute()
                                  .getCorpora();  // status: 403, error: Forbidden
System.out.println(corpus.get(0));
```

error:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ForbiddenException: Forbidden]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:251)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:178)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:363)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:361)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:413)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$Lambda$6244/000000001ECBEAD0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$$Lambda$3716/00000000172D40F0.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
Caused by: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.ForbiddenException: Forbidden
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:474)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$WatsonServiceCall.execute(WatsonService.java:532)
        at controllers.Controller.getCorpora(Controller.java:147)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$52(Routes.scala:1412)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$Lambda$6727/000000001FB17820.apply(Unknown Source)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$3.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:134)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$3.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:133)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$8$$anon$2$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:108)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:88)
        at play.http.DefaultActionCreator$1.call(DefaultActionCreator.java:31)
```

Comment: Why are there two "https://"s? Is that a typo?

Comment: @huytc it is a typo. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Watson Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk)!

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=java#get-a-corpus

Comment: thanks your comment! I used Watson SDK. But another error(403: forbidden) occurs...(I added some information)

Answer (score 0):

The example that Mike pointed to won't work with version 6, which is 2 major versions back. Can you update to version 8 of the SDK? See the [migration guide](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V8.md).

Then your authentication code would be different and the example in the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=java#get-a-corpus) should work:

```
IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator("{apikey}");
SpeechToText speechToText = new SpeechToText(authenticator);
speechToText.setServiceUrl("{url}");
```

replace `{url}` with `https://api.au-syd.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com` or `https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api`

and replace `{apikey}` with your key.

Comment: Thanks your comment! But I have to use the old version(6.9.2) by a constraint...